# Maven goal not attached to phase

Tags: java, maven, jetty, lifecycle

I'm trying to run some Selenium tests but it is not working to attach the starting of jetty to the pre-integration-test phase of maven. So  I tried to investigate the problem and it seems that in general Maven is not executing my goals in the phases I specified.

I found [this](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-attach-a-plugin-goal-to-a-particular-phase-of-a-maven-lifecycle.html) example and reproduced it. I created the plugin which works fine when I call it explicitly. But when I try to attach it to the validate phase and run mvn validate I don't see the "Hi there!!!" output. It simply shows me build success without calling the howdy-world goal :/ (which is consistent with my jetty not starting in integration-test phase)

How can I make this goal run when the validation phase is passed?

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
<artifactId>aproject</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>aproject</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-howdy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>howdy-world</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to do it that way:

```xml
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                <pluginExecutions>
                  <pluginExecution>
                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                      <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
                      <artifactId>maven-howdy-plugin</artifactId>
                      <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>howdy-world</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <action>
                      <ignore />
                    </action>
                  </pluginExecution>
                </pluginExecutions>
              </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-howdy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <!-- The following will really execute the plugin -->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.maventest</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-howdy-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>howdy-world</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>validate</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

The `pluginManagement` part is only intended to define versions and configuration for plugins but it will not really execute those plugins within the life-cycle.

Comment: thank you very much! that worked! But the weird thing is, that i get an error in eclipse at the execution-tag when its not in pluginManagement that says: "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.maventest:maven-howdy-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:howdy-world (execution: default, phase: validate)"

Comment: This is by the m2e plugin and not Maven. For this you should take a look here: http://eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Comment: so this tells me to use pluginmanagement which caused the problem. should i just ignore this eclipse error?

Comment: I have enhanced my answer with m2e configuration.